# Slicing multi index DataFrame into JSON object

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a `MultiIndex` `pd.DataFrame` that I generated from a `.txt` that is forecast model data.

##### Edit:

per request I've included a small data sample to generate the `DataFrame`

The `dict` below can be used to generate a more concise version of my data `DataFrame`

`data_dict:`

```py
{0: {('1000mb', 'gph'): 166.88, ('1000mb', 'temp'): 283.88, ('1000mb', 'dewpt'): 280.18, ('1000mb', 'dir'): 300.86, ('1000mb', 'speed'): 6.0, ('975mb', 'gph'): 377.88, ('975mb', 'temp'): 282.95, ('975mb', 'dewpt'): 278.56, ('975mb', 'dir'): 313.81, ('975mb', 'speed'): 13.0, ('950mb', 'gph'): 592.7, ('950mb', 'temp'): 280.97, ('950mb', 'dewpt'): 277.65, ('950mb', 'dir'): 319.71, ('950mb', 'speed'): 14.0, ('925mb', 'gph'): 811.98, ('925mb', 'temp'): 279.11, ('925mb', 'dewpt'): 276.72, ('925mb', 'dir'): 315.06, ('925mb', 'speed'): 13.0, ('900mb', 'gph'): 1035.98, ('900mb', 'temp'): 278.04, ('900mb', 'dewpt'): 276.56, ('900mb', 'dir'): 301.76, ('900mb', 'speed'): 10.0, ('875mb', 'gph'): 1266.98, ('875mb', 'temp'): 279.16, ('875mb', 'dewpt'): 277.68, ('875mb', 'dir'): 296.34, ('875mb', 'speed'): 8.0, ('850mb', 'gph'): 1503.98, ('850mb', 'temp'): 278.64, ('850mb', 'dewpt'): 276.81, ('850mb', 'dir'): 298.57, ('850mb', 'speed'): 9.0, ('825mb', 'gph'): 1747.98, ('825mb', 'temp'): 277.25, ('825mb', 'dewpt'): 275.69, ('825mb', 'dir'): 295.48, ('825mb', 'speed'): 11.0, ('800mb', 'gph'): 1998.26, ('800mb', 'temp'): 277.12, ('800mb', 'dewpt'): 273.89, ('800mb', 'dir'): 297.67, ('800mb', 'speed'): 13.0, ('775mb', 'gph'): 2256.98, ('775mb', 'temp'): 277.94, ('775mb', 'dewpt'): 272.48, ('775mb', 'dir'): 302.27, ('775mb', 'speed'): 15.0, ('750mb', 'gph'): 2523.86, ('750mb', 'temp'): 277.0, ('750mb', 'dewpt'): 270.96, ('750mb', 'dir'): 303.6, ('750mb', 'speed'): 16.0, ('725mb', 'gph'): 2798.8, ('725mb', 'temp'): 275.64, ('725mb', 'dewpt'): 269.21, ('725mb', 'dir'): 301.65, ('725mb', 'speed'): 19.0, ('700mb', 'gph'): 3081.8, ('700mb', 'temp'): 273.87, ('700mb', 'dewpt'): 266.74, ('700mb', 'dir'): 301.08, ('700mb', 'speed'): 23.0, ('675mb', 'gph'): 3371.96, ('675mb', 'temp'): 272.21, ('675mb', 'dewpt'): 263.85, ('675mb', 'dir'): 301.7, ('675mb', 'speed'): 25.0, ('650mb', 'gph'): 3673.08, ('650mb', 'temp'): 270.48, ('650mb', 'dewpt'): 260.75, ('650mb', 'dir'): 302.23, ('650mb', 'speed'): 28.0, ('625mb', 'gph'): 3982.04, ('625mb', 'temp'): 268.73, ('625mb', 'dewpt'): 257.99, ('625mb', 'dir'): 299.64, ('625mb', 'speed'): 29.0, ('600mb', 'gph'): 4303.62, ('600mb', 'temp'): 266.9, ('600mb', 'dewpt'): 255.05, ('600mb', 'dir'): 297.19, ('600mb', 'speed'): 30.0, ('575mb', 'gph'): 4633.92, ('575mb', 'temp'): 264.93, ('575mb', 'dewpt'): 251.89, ('575mb', 'dir'): 295.12, ('575mb', 'speed'): 31.0, ('550mb', 'gph'): 4978.9, ('550mb', 'temp'): 262.88, ('550mb', 'dewpt'): 248.45, ('550mb', 'dir'): 293.07, ('550mb', 'speed'): 32.0, ('525mb', 'gph'): 5333.54, ('525mb', 'temp'): 260.29, ('525mb', 'dewpt'): 245.08, ('525mb', 'dir'): 292.02, ('525mb', 'speed'): 33.0, ('500mb', 'gph'): 5705.5, ('500mb', 'temp'): 257.56, ('500mb', 'dewpt'): 241.47, ('500mb', 'dir'): 291.0, ('500mb', 'speed'): 35.0, ('475mb', 'gph'): 6087.4, ('475mb', 'temp'): 254.42, ('475mb', 'dewpt'): 241.58, ('475mb', 'dir'): 289.75, ('475mb', 'speed'): 34.0, ('450mb', 'gph'): 6489.96, ('450mb', 'temp'): 251.1, ('450mb', 'dewpt'): 240.94, ('450mb', 'dir'): 288.38, ('450mb', 'speed'): 33.0, ('425mb', 'gph'): 6904.36, ('425mb', 'temp'): 247.61, ('425mb', 'dewpt'): 237.23, ('425mb', 'dir'): 288.55, ('425mb', 'speed'): 34.0, ('400mb', 'gph'): 7343.9, ('400mb', 'temp'): 243.89, ('400mb', 'dewpt'): 233.3, ('400mb', 'dir'): 288.71, ('400mb', 'speed'): 36.0, ('375mb', 'gph'): 7798.15, ('375mb', 'temp'): 240.77, ('375mb', 'dewpt'): 226.58, ('375mb', 'dir'): 290.47, ('375mb', 'speed'): 43.0, ('350mb', 'gph'): 8283.76, ('350mb', 'temp'): 237.42, ('350mb', 'dewpt'): 216.64, ('350mb', 'dir'): 291.77, ('350mb', 'speed'): 52.0, ('325mb', 'gph'): 8790.03, ('325mb', 'temp'): 233.47, ('325mb', 'dewpt'): 217.34, ('325mb', 'dir'): 291.04, ('325mb', 'speed'): 57.0, ('300mb', 'gph'): 9336.86, ('300mb', 'temp'): 229.21, ('300mb', 'dewpt'): 216.5, ('300mb', 'dir'): 290.39, ('300mb', 'speed'): 62.0, ('275mb', 'gph'): 9909.55, ('275mb', 'temp'): 225.18, ('275mb', 'dewpt'): 214.54, ('275mb', 'dir'): 289.57, ('275mb', 'speed'): 62.0, ('250mb', 'gph'): 10536.86, ('250mb', 'temp'): 220.76, ('250mb', 'dewpt'): 211.98, ('250mb', 'dir'): 288.67, ('250mb', 'speed'): 62.0, ('225mb', 'gph'): 11209.65, ('225mb', 'temp'): 218.6, ('225mb', 'dewpt'): 208.69, ('225mb', 'dir'): 287.05, ('225mb', 'speed'): 62.0, ('200mb', 'gph'): 11961.78, ('200mb', 'temp'): 216.2, ('200mb', 'dewpt'): 204.77, ('200mb', 'dir'): 285.21, ('200mb', 'speed'): 62.0, ('175mb', 'gph'): 12805.89, ('175mb', 'temp'): 216.36, ('175mb', 'dewpt'): 201.73, ('175mb', 'dir'): 289.56, ('175mb', 'speed'): 56.0, ('150mb', 'gph'): 13780.35, ('150mb', 'temp'): 216.54, ('150mb', 'dewpt'): 194.67, ('150mb', 'dir'): 295.83, ('150mb', 'speed'): 49.0, ('125mb', 'gph'): 14929.06, ('125mb', 'temp'): 215.55, ('125mb', 'dewpt'): 193.0, ('125mb', 'dir'): 293.53, ('125mb', 'speed'): 41.0, ('100mb', 'gph'): 16334.96, ('100mb', 'temp'): 214.34, ('100mb', 'dewpt'): 190.78, ('100mb', 'dir'): 288.88, ('100mb', 'speed'): 30.0, ('75mb', 'gph'): 18128.15, ('75mb', 'temp'): 214.56, ('75mb', 'dewpt'): 189.31, ('75mb', 'dir'): 292.03, ('75mb', 'speed'): 22.0, ('50mb', 'gph'): 20655.52, ('50mb', 'temp'): 214.89, ('50mb', 'dewpt'): 186.13, ('50mb', 'dir'): 303.46, ('50mb', 'speed'): 12.0}, 1: {('1000mb', 'gph'): 165.16, ('1000mb', 'temp'): 283.48, ('1000mb', 'dewpt'): 280.17, ('1000mb', 'dir'): 305.02, ('1000mb', 'speed'): 6.0, ('975mb', 'gph'): 375.34, ('975mb', 'temp'): 282.49, ('975mb', 'dewpt'): 278.69, ('975mb', 'dir'): 317.14, ('975mb', 'speed'): 13.0, ('950mb', 'gph'): 590.16, ('950mb', 'temp'): 280.58, ('950mb', 'dewpt'): 277.87, ('950mb', 'dir'): 324.11, ('950mb', 'speed'): 13.0, ('925mb', 'gph'): 809.16, ('925mb', 'temp'): 278.92, ('925mb', 'dewpt'): 276.77, ('925mb', 'dir'): 313.02, ('925mb', 'speed'): 12.0, ('900mb', 'gph'): 1033.7, ('900mb', 'temp'): 278.32, ('900mb', 'dewpt'): 276.69, ('900mb', 'dir'): 291.26, ('900mb', 'speed'): 11.0, ('875mb', 'gph'): 1263.98, ('875mb', 'temp'): 279.08, ('875mb', 'dewpt'): 277.62, ('875mb', 'dir'): 281.37, ('875mb', 'speed'): 10.0, ('850mb', 'gph'): 1501.7, ('850mb', 'temp'): 278.63, ('850mb', 'dewpt'): 276.58, ('850mb', 'dir'): 283.97, ('850mb', 'speed'): 10.0, ('825mb', 'gph'): 1745.64, ('825mb', 'temp'): 277.59, ('825mb', 'dewpt'): 275.47, ('825mb', 'dir'): 289.33, ('825mb', 'speed'): 12.0, ('800mb', 'gph'): 1996.26, ('800mb', 'temp'): 277.69, ('800mb', 'dewpt'): 274.2, ('800mb', 'dir'): 296.36, ('800mb', 'speed'): 15.0, ('775mb', 'gph'): 2255.26, ('775mb', 'temp'): 278.15, ('775mb', 'dewpt'): 272.78, ('775mb', 'dir'): 297.89, ('775mb', 'speed'): 17.0, ('750mb', 'gph'): 2522.8, ('750mb', 'temp'): 276.96, ('750mb', 'dewpt'): 271.04, ('750mb', 'dir'): 294.99, ('750mb', 'speed'): 18.0, ('725mb', 'gph'): 2797.14, ('725mb', 'temp'): 275.4, ('725mb', 'dewpt'): 268.56, ('725mb', 'dir'): 294.07, ('725mb', 'speed'): 20.0, ('700mb', 'gph'): 3079.8, ('700mb', 'temp'): 273.71, ('700mb', 'dewpt'): 265.46, ('700mb', 'dir'): 296.39, ('700mb', 'speed'): 23.0, ('675mb', 'gph'): 3369.96, ('675mb', 'temp'): 272.08, ('675mb', 'dewpt'): 263.34, ('675mb', 'dir'): 300.0, ('675mb', 'speed'): 25.0, ('650mb', 'gph'): 3671.08, ('650mb', 'temp'): 270.39, ('650mb', 'dewpt'): 261.12, ('650mb', 'dir'): 303.18, ('650mb', 'speed'): 27.0, ('625mb', 'gph'): 3979.72, ('625mb', 'temp'): 268.74, ('625mb', 'dewpt'): 256.77, ('625mb', 'dir'): 301.49, ('625mb', 'speed'): 29.0, ('600mb', 'gph'): 4300.96, ('600mb', 'temp'): 267.02, ('600mb', 'dewpt'): 251.51, ('600mb', 'dir'): 299.96, ('600mb', 'speed'): 31.0, ('575mb', 'gph'): 4631.58, ('575mb', 'temp'): 264.99, ('575mb', 'dewpt'): 249.31, ('575mb', 'dir'): 297.06, ('575mb', 'speed'): 32.0, ('550mb', 'gph'): 4976.9, ('550mb', 'temp'): 262.87, ('550mb', 'dewpt'): 247.0, ('550mb', 'dir'): 294.2, ('550mb', 'speed'): 33.0, ('525mb', 'gph'): 5331.25, ('525mb', 'temp'): 260.22, ('525mb', 'dewpt'): 245.18, ('525mb', 'dir'): 293.26, ('525mb', 'speed'): 33.0, ('500mb', 'gph'): 5702.9, ('500mb', 'temp'): 257.43, ('500mb', 'dewpt'): 243.23, ('500mb', 'dir'): 292.32, ('500mb', 'speed'): 34.0, ('475mb', 'gph'): 6085.06, ('475mb', 'temp'): 254.43, ('475mb', 'dewpt'): 241.41, ('475mb', 'dir'): 291.09, ('475mb', 'speed'): 34.0, ('450mb', 'gph'): 6487.9, ('450mb', 'temp'): 251.26, ('450mb', 'dewpt'): 239.39, ('450mb', 'dir'): 289.79, ('450mb', 'speed'): 34.0, ('425mb', 'gph'): 6902.76, ('425mb', 'temp'): 248.02, ('425mb', 'dewpt'): 233.63, ('425mb', 'dir'): 293.14, ('425mb', 'speed'): 38.0, ('400mb', 'gph'): 7342.78, ('400mb', 'temp'): 244.58, ('400mb', 'dewpt'): 226.55, ('400mb', 'dir'): 295.98, ('400mb', 'speed'): 43.0, ('375mb', 'gph'): 7798.48, ('375mb', 'temp'): 241.27, ('375mb', 'dewpt'): 223.77, ('375mb', 'dir'): 295.9, ('375mb', 'speed'): 49.0, ('350mb', 'gph'): 8285.64, ('350mb', 'temp'): 237.73, ('350mb', 'dewpt'): 220.79, ('350mb', 'dir'): 295.83, ('350mb', 'speed'): 55.0, ('325mb', 'gph'): 8791.36, ('325mb', 'temp'): 233.48, ('325mb', 'dewpt'): 220.96, ('325mb', 'dir'): 292.78, ('325mb', 'speed'): 57.0, ('300mb', 'gph'): 9337.58, ('300mb', 'temp'): 228.89, ('300mb', 'dewpt'): 219.65, ('300mb', 'dir'): 289.8, ('300mb', 'speed'): 60.0, ('275mb', 'gph'): 9909.7, ('275mb', 'temp'): 225.04, ('275mb', 'dewpt'): 216.01, ('275mb', 'dir'): 288.82, ('275mb', 'speed'): 60.0, ('250mb', 'gph'): 10536.4, ('250mb', 'temp'): 220.82, ('250mb', 'dewpt'): 212.03, ('250mb', 'dir'): 287.75, ('250mb', 'speed'): 60.0, ('225mb', 'gph'): 11207.71, ('225mb', 'temp'): 218.23, ('225mb', 'dewpt'): 208.96, ('225mb', 'dir'): 285.43, ('225mb', 'speed'): 61.0, ('200mb', 'gph'): 11958.17, ('200mb', 'temp'): 215.33, ('200mb', 'dewpt'): 205.5, ('200mb', 'dir'): 282.93, ('200mb', 'speed'): 63.0, ('175mb', 'gph'): 12802.98, ('175mb', 'temp'): 216.25, ('175mb', 'dewpt'): 202.77, ('175mb', 'dir'): 287.48, ('175mb', 'speed'): 56.0, ('150mb', 'gph'): 13778.24, ('150mb', 'temp'): 217.31, ('150mb', 'dewpt'): 194.46, ('150mb', 'dir'): 294.22, ('150mb', 'speed'): 49.0, ('125mb', 'gph'): 14926.09, ('125mb', 'temp'): 215.54, ('125mb', 'dewpt'): 192.81, ('125mb', 'dir'): 292.33, ('125mb', 'speed'): 42.0, ('100mb', 'gph'): 16330.96, ('100mb', 'temp'): 213.37, ('100mb', 'dewpt'): 190.79, ('100mb', 'dir'): 288.86, ('100mb', 'speed'): 33.0, ('75mb', 'gph'): 18120.98, ('75mb', 'temp'): 214.0, ('75mb', 'dewpt'): 189.51, ('75mb', 'dir'): 291.2, ('75mb', 'speed'): 24.0, ('50mb', 'gph'): 20643.88, ('50mb', 'temp'): 214.89, ('50mb', 'dewpt'): 186.35, ('50mb', 'dir'): 300.53, ('50mb', 'speed'): 12.0}}
```

In the `data` provided above the I dropped the unused values as such...

```py
PROPS_2_DROP = ['gph_dval', 'temp_dval', 'clouds', 'fl-vis', 'icing_type', 'cwmr',
                'rh', 'theta-e', 'parcel_temp', 'vvs', 'mixing_ratio', 'turbulence']
midf = self.DataFrame[range(0, 2)].drop('sfc').drop(labels=PROPS_2_DROP, level='props')
midf.to_dict(orient='dict' )
```

`data_dict` -> `MultiIndex.DataFrame`

```
midf = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
```

`DataFrame`

```py
                       0        1        2        3        4        5    ...      139      140      141      142      143      144
lvl  props                                                               ...                                                      
sfc  mean_slp      1019.73  1019.50  1019.19  1018.83  1019.03  1019.02  ...   995.10   995.44   995.79   995.99   996.20   996.41
     altimeter       30.10    30.09    30.09    30.07    30.08    30.08  ...    29.37    29.38    29.39    29.40    29.40    29.41
     press_alt      285.78   291.39   299.50   309.49   304.92   305.71  ...   963.21   953.97   944.74   939.51   934.28   929.05
     density_alt    -55.22   -88.18  -135.38  -186.09  -235.12  -262.16  ...  1265.79  1224.16  1182.28  1137.12  1091.92  1046.88
     2_m_agl_tmp    283.50   283.17   282.70   282.18   281.82   281.59  ...   287.05   286.84   286.62   286.34   286.06   285.78
...                    ...      ...      ...      ...      ...      ...  ...      ...      ...      ...      ...      ...      ...
50mb mixing_ratio     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00  ...     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00
     cwmr             0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00  ...     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00
     icing_type      -1.00    -1.00    -1.00    -1.00    -1.00    -1.00  ...    -1.00    -1.00    -1.00    -1.00    -1.00    -1.00
     turbulence       0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00  ...     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00
     vvs              0.00     0.00    -0.00    -0.00    -0.00     0.00  ...    -0.00    -0.00    -0.00    -0.00    -0.00     0.00

[804 rows x 145 columns]
```

There are various methods for working with the forecast DataFrame.  The one I've been working on tonight slices and structures data into a `JSON` object that is sent to a `TypeScript` application.

`types`

```js
type Dataset = Datum[][];
type Datums = Datum[];
interface Datum {
    press: number;
    hght: number;
    temp: number;
    dwpt: number;
    wdir: number;
    wspd: number;
};
```

`method`

```py
DICT_KEYS = ['temp', 'dwpt', 'wdir', 'wspd', 'hght', 'press']
ABSOLUTE_ZERO = -273.15
def feature_skewt_dataset(self, start=0, stop=30) -> Dict[str, List[List[Dict[str, int]]]]:
    # slice multi-index-dataframe time by argument range
    midf = self.DataFrame[range(start, stop)]

    # kelvin to celcius
    temperature = midf.loc[(slice(None), "temp"), :] + ABSOLUTE_ZERO # - 273.15
    dewpoint = midf.loc[(slice(None), "dewpt"), :] + ABSOLUTE_ZERO #- 273.15
    wind_speed = midf.loc[(slice(None), "speed"), :]
    wind_direction = midf.loc[(slice(None), "dir"), :]
    geopotential_height = midf.loc[(slice(None), "gph"), :]
    # milibars = self._make_mbars(39)
    # milibars = midf.droplevel(1).index.unique().str.strip('mb')
    milibars = midf.index.get_level_values('lvl').unique().str.rstrip('mb')

    # STEP 3 zip the keys -> stack
    dataset = [[dict(zip(DICT_KEYS, stack))for stack in np.column_stack([
        # STEP 2 ->  slice the properties by the time index
        temperature.loc[:, time_index],
        dewpoint.loc[:, time_index],
        wind_direction.loc[:, time_index],
        wind_speed.loc[:, time_index],
        geopotential_height.loc[:, time_index],
        milibars
    # STEP 1 -> iterate the time_index column index
    ]).astype(int)] for time_index in midf.columns]

    return {'dataset': dataset}
```

Comment: Can you include code for a small sample dataframe so that this is executable?

Comment: I went ahead and updated the post with some starting data. Thanks!

Comment: Please show the definition of `_make_mbars`

Comment: `milibars = midf.droplevel(1).index.unique( ).str.strip('mb')`

Comment: Please do not edit the question, especially the code, after an answer has been posted. Changing the question may cause answer invalidation. Everyone needs to be able to see what the reviewer was referring to. [What to do after the question has been answered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). You can ask a follow up question with a link back to this question if you feel you need a re-review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's good that you provided `data_dict`. In my suggested code, I had first dumped this dataframe to a pickle to be able to get it back without fuss and without having to include it in the source code verbatim.

You initially didn't define your pressure quantity; `_make_mbars` was missing. You now say that it's effectively

```
midf.droplevel(1).index.unique( ).str.strip('mb')
```

but this is non-ideal for a collection of reasons:

- you don't actually want to get unique values, but instead want to associate each value with a row;
- you should use `rstrip` instead of `strip`;
- you need to cast to integers; and
- rather than `droplevel`, for this use you should just use `get_level_values`.

Likewise, you failed to provide the whole class so I ignored `self` and just accepted a starting dataframe as a function parameter.

You're over-abbreviating your column and variable names. Just write the names in plain English. You offered two reasons for the abbreviated names, the first being that you need to adhere to a [NOAA format](https://rucsoundings.noaa.gov/raob_format.html). Externally that's fine; but internally you should use sane names and not the names you're required to use in external serialised formats.

The second reason you offered for over-abbreviation is

> they are being called in a React d3 application [...] frequently

Cutting a couple of characters in your field names is premature and mis-directed optimisation. There are plenty of opportunities for actual optimisation elsewhere.

Put `273.15` into a constant rather than leaving it as a magic number. When you subtract this number, it's probably a good idea to `round()`; I was conservative and rounded to 12 decimals to cut the error. This is only possible because your real data stop at two decimals.

Most of your difficulty comes from the fact that your data frame is effectively rotated, and needs to be rotated again to be sane. In Pandas terminology this rotation is called stacking. You need to `unstack` your property names to columns, and you need to `stack` your time columns to indices. Once this is done, the data are much, much easier to manipulate with (nearly) stock Pandas functions.

### Suggested

```
from pprint import pprint

import pandas as pd

ABSOLUTE_ZERO = -273.15


def kelvin_to_celsius(temperature: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    return (temperature + ABSOLUTE_ZERO).round(decimals=12)


def sanitise(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    stacked: pd.DataFrame = df.stack().unstack(level=1)
    stacked.rename(
        columns={
            'dewpt': 'dewpoint',
            'gph': 'height',
            'dir': 'wind_direction',
            'speed': 'wind_speed',
            'temp': 'temperature',
        },
        inplace=True,
    )

    stacked.temperature = kelvin_to_celsius(stacked.temperature)
    stacked.dewpoint = kelvin_to_celsius(stacked.dewpoint)

    stacked['pressure'] = (
        stacked.index.get_level_values(level=0)
        .str.rstrip('mb').astype(int)
    )
    return stacked.droplevel(0)


def feature_skewt_dataset(
    midf: pd.DataFrame,
    start_time: int = 0,
    stop_time: int = 30,
) -> dict[str, list]:
    # Since the index only contains time and is non-unique, we cannot use
    # to_dict(orient='index')

    return {
        'dataset': [
            midf.loc[time_index].to_dict(orient='records')
            for time_index in range(start_time, stop_time)
        ]
    }


def test() -> None:
    insane = pd.read_pickle('midf.pickle')
    sane = sanitise(insane)
    dataset = feature_skewt_dataset(sane, stop_time=2)
    pprint(dataset)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look overt this tonight.  I'm on the night shift and just getting my morning coffee.  I'll get back to you in a bit.

Comment: `_make_mbars` can be replaced with

`milibars = midf.droplevel(1).index.unique( ).str.strip('mb')`

is just the numeric value of the `XXmb` index

Comment: I made a minor adjustment to my code to remove the destructing with a `dict(zip())`.  

The purpose behind the abbreviated dict keys is they are being called in a `React` `d3` application. Where function like  `d3.line().curve(curveLinear).x((d) => x(d.dwpt) + (y(P.base) - y(d.press)) / tangent)` are being called frequently

Comment: Sure; edited. Frequent calls are not a good reason to mutilate your names.

Comment: `Most of your difficulty comes from the fact that your data frame is effectively rotated, and needs to be rotated again to be sane.` 

In my rotated `Dataframe`  need to create a essentially a `NDarray` of `{properties}[height][time]`

Comment: I mean... OK? I don't think your original code was doing that, so if you need that reviewed you need to post a new question. If you don't know how to do that, you'll need to switch to StackOverflow.

Comment: It does, and yours does as well.
\n
                    TINDEX_0                             TINDEX_1
`[ [ { props }, { props }, { props } ], [ { props }, { props }, { props } ] ...]`

each props value has a different height and millibars measurement of atmospheric pressure.

Comment: the purpose behind the names is because of the javascript library the data is being put into.  https://github.com/rittels/skewt-js.  This was the repo I based alot of my client application development around, and I just went with that format.  If I was writing a key for a python specific usage it would be different, I suppose.

Comment: internally the dataframe names are being generated from the source file.

which is a sloppy `csv`  `975mb  Speed(kt): ` `1000mb  Clouds(%):` `VIL-D Gusts (kt):`

the keys are generated from a method


k = re.split(r'(?<=mb)\s* ', key)

lvl, prop = (k if len(k) > 1 else ["sfc", k[0]])

prop = re.sub(r"\s+", "_", re.sub(r"\s*(?=\().*|\s*(?=:).*", "", prop)).lower()

return (lvl, prop)
`

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/269398/using-pandas-and-numpy-to-parse-dirty-csv

I've refactored the entire parsing method, but this will give you a perspective of my starting point.

Comment: @Reinderien Please check if there has been an answer invalidation in the edits, I can't tell for sure.